# When to use vectorization and when to use loops or apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, apply

I am trying to understand how different type of iterations work in Python

For example following line will go through every line of dataframe all of the data frames

```py
portfolio_pnl = (
(aapl_position - aapl_position.shift()) 
+ (amzn_position - amzn_position.shift())
)
```

Yet in the following situation, one has to use apply to ensure that a function is applied to every line

```py
s = pd.read_csv("stock.csv", squeeze = True)
#### adding 5 to each value
new = s.apply(lambda num : num + 5)
```

So my question is:  Where and how would one know to use `apply` or any other loop and where would one can just need to use a formula and expect that to be applied on every line by itself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use [Minimal Reproducible Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of throwing around random code segments with unintelligible variable names.

Comment: You add 5 to each value with `new = s + 5`. Use `apply` if you need to apply a more complicated function, not adding a constant –or a shifted datraframe, which is more or less like adding a constant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

Comment: the conventional form of iterations (`for loop`) and a Dataframe which is vectorised are different...

Comment: Please note that this is not exactly a Python concept.  This is a pandas and numpy concept.  Those packages override the normal operators to operate on the entire array at once.  If you do `[1,2,3] + [4,5,6]`, you'll get a very different answer (specifically, concatenation -- `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`).